# Django Rest return 0 bytes zip file in response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have simple method that return zip archive with .pdf file in it.
Here is part of code that generate zip archive and return it:

```
pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf()
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
with archive:
    archive.writestr('report.pdf', pdf_file)
wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)

http_response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip')
http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.zip'

return http_response
```

The problem is that I get in response 0 byte zip archive. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATED**

Also I add this 2 lines of code before `return` but with it I get `seek of closed file`

```
http_response['Content_Length'] = temp.tell()
temp.seek(0)
```

Comment: seems you should add temp.seek()

Comment: @AndreyBerenda, I use it before, but with it I get "seek of closed file" error

Comment: `HttpResponse` will fully consume the file when you create it. Try placing the `temp.seek()` call before you create the `HttpResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help to @Will Keeling

I resolve my problem by adding `temp.seek()` before `HttpResponse` and remove `http_response['Content_Length'] = temp.tell()` becouse we can not use temp after it closed.